# Как сконфигурировать сайт на вордпресс и плагины, чтобы заработало REST API?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, wordpress-плагины, wordpress-multisite

Есть одностраничный сайт на WP: https://page.ninjamail.click/
Нужно сделать, чтобы на нём заработал REST API
Пробовал установить эти плагины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код для авториазции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
string wpLogin = "";
string wpPassword = "";
var client = new WordPressClient("https://page.ninjamail.click/wp-json");
client.Auth.UseBearerAuth(JWTPlugin.JWTAuthByUsefulTeam);
await client.Auth.RequestJWTokenAsync(wpLogin, wpPassword);
```

Я полагаю, REST API не настроено и установить плагин мало
надо модицифировать сайт для поддержки JWT авторизации

Как это сделать?

Comment: REST API в ВП по умолчанию включён ещё с версии 4.4, если я правильно помню. И настраивать ничего не надо. Надо просто читать [документацию](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) и делать как положено.

Comment: @SeVlad вроде всё правильно сделал, но не работает....

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin сделал

Comment: @Vadzim Вы не совсем верно ставите вопрос. Само REST API на Вашем сайте вполне себе работает, просто перейдите по ссылке [https://page.ninjamail.click/wp-json](https://page.ninjamail.click/wp-json), и можете даже получить контент конкретной страницы [https://page.ninjamail.click/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/6](https://page.ninjamail.click/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/6).

Comment: @Vadzim а на счет работы JWT авторизации, то в принципе в зависимости от того, каким плагином Вы пользуетесь, там вполне себе описано что конкретно нужно сделать [https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/)

Comment: @Simon установил его. Внёс правки в код. Теперь выдаёт такое https://page.ninjamail.click/wp-json

Comment: `Authorization header not found.`?

Comment: @Simon в чём ошибка?

Comment: @Simon да. именно это.

Comment: @Simon как с помощью postman отредактировать запись на этом сайте.

Comment: А где Вы вообще взяли тот код что приводите в сниппете и почему думаете что он должен работать? Вам же нужно для начала токен сгенерировать и так далее.

Comment: @Simon подскажите пожалуйста как его сгенерировать.

Comment: Все же есть на странице плагина или на его Github. [Requesting/ Generating Token](https://github.com/usefulteam/jwt-auth#requesting-generating-token)